# Toggle setVisibility for swt widget

Tags: java, swt, jface, rcp

I have a `TitleAreaDialog` with few buttons and a `ProgressBar`, upon selecting any of the buttons certain operation will be performed, so I would be needing the `ProgressBar` to indicate the user that some operation is in-progress. Since the time is unknown I am creating the progress bar globally, with type as `SWT.INDETERMINATE` and `setVisibility(false)` (so that the progress will be displayed only upon triggering the button listener) and whenever the button is pressed following is performed,

1. `progressBar.setVisible(true)`
2. perform the operation (progressBar should be active ie., should show as loading)
3. `progressBar.setVisible(false)`

Is this the correct way? because i didn't get the output desired.
I need the progress bar to be available/visible only when the operation is being performed and not throughout the dialog life.

Comment: You would be better off using a single page Wizard - wizard has built in progress bar support.

Answer (score 1):

When your button operation runs in the UI thread, the progressBar can't be updated. You could use a Job to do the operation in background:

```
public class MyLayout {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        final Display display = new Display ();
        Shell shell = new Shell (display);
        RowLayout rowLayout = new RowLayout ();
        shell.setLayout (rowLayout);

        Button button = new Button (shell, SWT.PUSH);
        button.setText ("button0");

        final ProgressBar progressbar = new ProgressBar (shell, SWT.NONE);
        progressbar.setSelection (50);
        progressbar.setVisible(false);

        button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {

            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                progressbar.setVisible(true);
                // make a background operation
                Job job = new Job("Button...") {

                    @Override
                    protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
                        // do the button operation...
                        return Status.OK_STATUS;
                    }
                };
                job.addJobChangeListener(new JobChangeAdapter() {

                    @Override
                    public void done(IJobChangeEvent jobEvent) {
                        // update progressbar in UI thread 
                        display.syncExec(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                progressbar.setVisible(false);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                });
                job.schedule();
            }
        });

        shell.pack ();
        shell.open ();

        while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch ())
                display.sleep ();
        }
        display.dispose ();
    }
}
```

But the Job itself also provides a monitor to show the user that an operation is in progress.